# OnPaint override cannot draw white text on top of picture boxes

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, gdi+

I am writing an application that edits meta data of songs. To do this I have a window that has selected song tags and you can choose between the old and the new. I have a custom control with 3 pictureboxes in it for each tag box. One picture box for the left cap, one for the middle and one for the right cap. I then have overwritten OnPaint for the UserControl to draw the text onto the control. This works fine except when I try to use white text on top of a picture box that has an image in it. The white seems to become semi transparent. I have attached pictures below demonstrating this.

**Black Text**

[Image of Black Text http://bentrengrove.com.au/blackText.PNG](http://bentrengrove.com.au/blackText.PNG)

**White Text**

[Image of White Text http://bentrengrove.com.au/WhiteText.PNG](http://bentrengrove.com.au/WhiteText.PNG)

**Here is the code for my OnPaint method**

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Brush b;
    Font f;

    if (_isSelected && this.Enabled) //Determines if the tag has the boxes visible, i.e is a selected tag
    {
        b = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        f = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
    }
    else
    {
        b = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray);
        f = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
    }

    var textSize = g.MeasureString(_text, f); //We will resize the tag boxes based on the size of the text
    StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat();
    drawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;

    RectangleF layoutRectangle = new RectangleF(leftCap.Width, 1, textSize.Width, 16);

    if (textSize.Width >= 105)
        _text = String.Format("{0}...", _text.Substring(0, 15)); //There is only so much room to display text

    middle.Width = (int)textSize.Width + rightCap.Width;
    rightCap.Left = middle.Left + middle.Width - rightCap.Width;

    g.DrawString(_text, f, b, layoutRectangle, drawFormat); //Draw the string for this control based on what has been set to text

    //Clean up
    g.Dispose();
    b.Dispose();
    f.Dispose();
}
```

Please if anyone has any ideas why I can't draw in white the help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it show better if you use a bigger font? Does setting the FontStyle to FontStyle.Bold help?  I have a feeling it's an antialiasing issue.

Comment: No unfortunately it has the same problem, appears slightly gray but in bold.

Comment: Picture of bold text: [link](http://bentrengrove.com.au/BoldText.PNG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem myself. The problem is due to the order items are painted on the form. Because I was painting over a picturebox in the controls OnPaint method, OnPaint is called first. Even with base.OnPaint being the first item in my onPaint method, the Painting of the controls are painted after this method finishes. By removing the middle picturebox and painting its image inside OnPaint the text draws white correctly. I am still not sure why this problem only appears on white text and does not occur on other colors.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure that the brush you end up using is white?  Can you verify that both `_isSelected` and `this.Enabled` is `true`?  Check in the debugger to see the values.

I put some `Gray` text on a `DimGray` background and it looks similar to how you have it now.

[image: sample]

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
    using (Font f = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, 8f, FontStyle.Regular))
    {
        pe.Graphics.DrawString(
            "Foo",
            f,
            Brushes.Black,
            new PointF(5, 5),
            new StringFormat
            {
                Alignment = StringAlignment.Near,
            });
        pe.Graphics.DrawString(
            "Bar",
            f,
            Brushes.Gray,
            new PointF(5, 20),
            new StringFormat
            {
                Alignment = StringAlignment.Near,
            });
        pe.Graphics.DrawString(
            "Bar",
            f,
            Brushes.White,
            new PointF(5, 35),
            new StringFormat
            {
                Alignment = StringAlignment.Near,
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but the brush I end up with is indeed white. I have tested it, for example I can change the color of the Color.White to any color and it will draw correctly in that Color. Just white seems to have a problem.

Comment: How about increasing the size of the font, changing the background color to something darker, etc. Could be the OS taking over for "readability."
Edit: Jeff M has "8f" instead of "8" for the Font parameters. Try that?

Comment: Changing the font size to 8f has not worked either. I have also tried playing with the settings of TextContrast and TextRenderingHint to no success. I am now going to try to remove the picturebox and draw the image using GraphicsContext instead.